# Kentico integration with SAP

Tags: content-management-system, integration, sap, kentico

Just curious if there are any opinions on what is the best approach for integrating Kentico CMS with SAP for two way reading/writing.  Is it to use the Kentico API, the SAP API or something like the Kentico integration bus?

Comment: SAP is a huge software company. It depends which SAP software you are talking about...

Answer (score 1):

With Kentico's Integration Bus you'll be using the Kentico API to interact with another system.  Having worked with SAP just briefly, I'd recommend looking into the options you have with SAP.  What I remember is the newer version(s) have some tools called Process Orchestration which will allow you to interact with SAP from an external system.

If you don't need the data to be live or updated immediately when the transaction happens AND you don't need robust tracking, logging or error handling then use a [scheduled task](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Scheduling+custom+tasks).  You will have to add your own logic for what happens if a record transfer fails or when they succeed.  You will also schedule this through the Kentico UI to run at a given time.  This process works well for a one-way sync/data transfer process.  For instance updating all the products descriptions in Kentico from a master system.  Or running an import of all your staff into a custom table.

If you need immediate processing (one or both ways) as well as robust error handling where if something fails within Kentico, it will be stored and processed later OOTB then look into [Integration Bus](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Using+the+integration+bus).  The Integration Bus handles transactions asynchronously which is a very nice feature.

The best approach is really specific to your project, not every one is the same or can you justify using one over the other every time.